# web-component-tester fails for yeoman generator-polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, yeoman, selenium-chromedriver

With the default Polymer app setup provided from Yeoman generator-polymer 0.7.2 with Gulp selected, Web Component Tester (`gulp test:local`) is failing with the following error when testing Chrome versions 42 and 43:

> Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
>       at   Context. at /app/test/yo-greeting-basic.html:22:0

Line 22 of yo-greeting-basic.html looks like this:

```js
    var header = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('h1');
```

so it seems the problem is a lack of shadow DOM support.

I also get the error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
>       at   Context. at /app/test/yo-list-basic.html:23:0

where lines 22-23 of yo-list-basic.html are

```js
    var el = document.querySelector('yo-list');
    el.items.push('Foo');
```

and `yo-list` is the name of the Polymer element defined in yo-list.html. I'm guessing it's the same issue -- the items aren't found because they're in the shadow DOM.

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and I have Chrome 42 and 43 installed. 
I understand that [Chrome Driver 2.14](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/notes.txt) has shadow DOM support but I haven't been able to find documentation for setting it up with web-component-tester.

Can someone tell me what I need to do to get these tests to work?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is probably because WCT is running its own server and 404ing on the resources coming from `bower_components`. A recent change moved the `bower_components` dir out of `app` and it looks like that broke wct. I'll fix this in the next release which should be going out very soon. I'll update this answer when the new release lands.

Comment: hm the generator just clones the Polymer Starter Kit project now: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit

Are you still seeing an issue? If so, I'd suggest filing a ticket on that repo